# Pyautogui not moving visual mouse in parallel or RDP windows 10

Tags: python, pyautogui

I’m trying to run a pyautogui script in a RDP or parallel virtual machine but I have encountered this problem with controlling the mouse. The problem is that pyautogui does not move the visual mouse but seem to move an invisible mouse that is able to move click on my predefined coordinate.

This is fine for a lot of stuff but what can I do if I want the visual mouse to move?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Clicknium to control the mouse. It provides a function that you can call to move the mouse.
https://www.clicknium.com/documents/references/python/mouse/move

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).